# Cambiar @page size en tiempo de ejecución (runtime)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Tengo el siguiente `css`

```
  @page { 
    margin: 0; 
    size: 7.8cm ;
  }
```

Quiero cambiar la altura (height) usando ´javascript´ o ´jquery´, ¿Alguien sabe como?

Comment: a que etiqueta HTML afecta @page?

Comment: @page solo aplica para documentos impresos, ¿estás seguro que es la regla que necesitas?

Comment: exactamente es la idea, al documento impreso no al div en pantalla

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo un fragmento, básicamente, tienes que capturar la altura actual del selector, en mi caso es `.page`, y como ejemplo definí que en cada click aumente su tamaño en 10 px.

Espero te sirva

```js
$(function(){
 
 $(document).on('click','#btn',function(){
   let h = $('.page').height() + 10;
   $('.page').css('min-height', h);
 });
});
```

```css
.page{
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="¡Más grande!" id="btn">
<div class="page">
</div>
```